# How to rotate a stack from element's center in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, transform

I have a following code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'dart:math' as math;

void main() {
  debugPaintSizeEnabled = true;
  return runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
        body: SafeArea(
          child: ImageRotate(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ImageRotate extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Transform.rotate(
      angle: (math.pi / 180) * 45,
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned(
            top: 100,
            left: 50,
            child: Image.network(
              "https://via.placeholder.com/300x200",
              height: 200,
              width: 300,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Now what I expect is the rotation to be executed from center of the image like so,

[image]

Instead it rotates like so,

[image]

I also tried looking into transform origin. But I couldn't figure out the origin's offset by myself. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the code you gave you yields the error? When I execute it I see exactly the first picture (ie what you want to have)

Comment: @Lulupointu I'm sorry. That's the wrong code.

Comment: @Lulupointu Updated the code.

Comment: the code you posted (Stack>Positioned>Transform.rotate>Image.asset) displays the first image (expected one) so i dont really know what your problem is

Comment: You want to rotate the entire stack based on the center of your image ?

Comment: and now if you rotate the entire `Stack`with the pivot point in the stack center  the expected result is image two (you see the stack bounds drawn with blue lines?)

Comment: @pskink The stack can have many more elements so I want to rotate the entire stack i.e. (Transform.rotate>Stack>Positioned>Image.asset).

Comment: @Lulupointu Right.

Comment: so the output is correct - the entire stack is rotated - for example add some `Icon` in the bottom right corner in the stack and you will see how it works

Comment: @pskink Yeah but the center of rotation should be the image. You know what I mean?

Comment: Yeah but not around the center of the image, it's rotated on the center of the stack itself

Comment: so change the `alignment` for `Transform.rotate` - you can also play with `origin`

Comment: @pskink This is what I want precisely https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64347904/calculating-coordinates-based-on-the-angle-in-flutter. Instead of rotating the whole stack, I want to calculate the coordinates and move the elements accordingly..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were in the right direction while trying to get the position of the image (you also need it's size in order to rotate in function of the *center*).

In order to do this, the classic method in flutter is to use keys.
Here is your problem with the use of this method:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'dart:math' as math;

void main() {
  debugPaintSizeEnabled = true;
  return runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
          body: ImageRotate(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ImageRotate extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ImageRotateState createState() => _ImageRotateState();
}

class _ImageRotateState extends State<ImageRotate> {
  final GlobalKey imageKey = GlobalKey();
  Size imageSize = Size(0, 0);
  Offset imagePos = Offset.zero;

  @override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      imageSize = (imageKey.currentContext.findRenderObject() as RenderBox).size;
      imagePos =
          (imageKey.currentContext.findRenderObject() as RenderBox).localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
      setState(() {});
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(imagePos);
    print(imageSize);
    return Transform.rotate(
      angle: imagePos == Offset.zero ? 0 : (math.pi / 180) * 45,
      origin:
          -Offset(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, MediaQuery.of(context).size.height) / 2 +
              (imagePos + Offset(imageSize.width / 2, imageSize.height / 2)),
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned(
            top: 200,
            left: 300,
            child: Image.network(
              "https://via.placeholder.com/300x200",
              key: imageKey,
              height: 100,
              width: 100,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Calculus explanation**: The origin is the offset of the center. That's why you have to shift it by `-Offset(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, MediaQuery.of(context).size.height)/2`. It places the center on the top left of the screen. And then you move to go to the center of the image so here you use the dimensions that you got from the GlobalKey: `(imagePos + Offset(imageSize.width / 2, imageSize.height / 2))`

**`imagePos == Offset.zero ? 0 : (math.pi / 180) * 45` explanation**: You have to first get the position of the image when their is no rotation, so you first set the rotation to zero, then the imagePos is calculated, then you can apply the rotation angle that you want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Lulupointu. But I don't get the desired result still. I treid your code in https://dartpad.dartlang.org/. THe image is outside of canvas.

Comment: If it's not too much to ask, would you help me with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64347904/calculating-coordinates-based-on-the-angle-in-flutter? @Lulupointu. Instead of rotating stack, I would only rotate the image annd move other elements accordingly.

Comment: I'm looking into this one first

Comment: I can't believe I missed this lol. Thanks @Lulupointu